# GWT development mode is quiet

Tags: gwt, development-mode

I'm developing a project with GWT for quite some months but since two weeks or so i get no more feedback in the jetty development mode window when an error occures...

How could that come?? Could it be caused by some missconfiguration of the logging module? Some errors appear on the console of the started jetty application as [INFO].

Answer (score 1):

The strange behaviour with GWT can happen if:

- You have "server" (not included source code) class
- You have only import to server class
- One of your bean used to communication by service is not serializable (or not extends IsSerializable) or any of it attributes is not serializable
- Your bean used to communication by service do not have not parameters constructor (or any of parent class)
- Your bean used to communication by service has final field

  I had almost all from this when I searched why my code is broken. I did not included all cases of course :)

**Update**

In our project we extends AsyncCallback

```
public abstract class MyAsyncCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
            

    @Override
    public final void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        yourLogger.log(caught);

        onFailureDefault(caught);
    }

    protected abstract void onFailureImpl(Throwable caught);

}
```

You has to replace all your AsyncCallback with this. Now you have control on errors. Sometimes there are suppressed by wrong error handling.

See also [GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions but does not help me =/ yes all my objects that I use for RPC calls are serializable. I don't see any reason for your rules to be set on client activities, places, grids and UI components...

Answer (score 1):

Try CCleaner Software and clean all Recent files, browser Cache, Temporary files etc. Then just restart eclipse or better restart the entire System. Also, check if you have GWT.log("MESSAGE") method called for Errors/Exceptions.

Comment: yes.. "mvn clean" & "mvn eclipse:clean" & "mvn eclipse:eclipse" & "mvn gwt:clean" & "mvn gwt:eclipse" does not help. What you mean with "check GWT.log" called? don't get it

Comment: GWT will create a lot of Temporary files. Thats why i suggest a clean up of your System

Comment: Can you tell me where actually you need to get the response from Jetty?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late response... When an Activity could not be started, which was often caused by an null pointer exception, i don't get any error message from Jetty. I often had the problem that i use an object which was not initialized in that status but jetty does not give me any feedback so debugging needs lot of more time than usual.... =/